# read/write an online .wav file in matlab?

Tags: html, matlab, url

I am currently working on a signal processing lab for school that requires me to download and analyze a .wav file. I was wondering if there was a way to `wavread()` or `wavwrite()` a URL so I don't have to re-download the audio file every-time I move to a new computer or send the code to the members of my group?

All the files can be found [here](http://www.soe.uoguelph.ca/webfiles/sgregori/signal.html).
And this is the url for one of the .wav files:
http://www.soe.uoguelph.ca/webfiles/sgregori/Audio/speech.wav

I have tried  `urlread()` and `urlwrite()` but to be honest I don't quite understand what to do with the html coding. I have also tried:

```
[x,fs]=wavread('http://www.soe.uoguelph.ca/webfiles/sgregori/Audio/speech.wav');
```

but ended up with the error:

> Error using wavread (line 67)
>   Invalid Wave File. Reason: Cannot open file.

I am also using the student version of Matlab so maybe that is the issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: you'll anyway download these wav files everytime in order to read them on different computer, that's what happens when you use the internet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
urlwrite('http://www.soe.uoguelph.ca/webfiles/sgregori/Audio/speech.wav','s1.wav');
```

This saves a file `s1.wav` to the directory you work on. Then line

```
[x,fs]=wavread('s1');
```

should work fine